# Why do I get an error when creating a new module in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-module

So I just created a new module and everything on the module is red. I'm not sure what's happening?

[image]

The error message is shown above

Comment: If you post images of code or error messages, please also copy/paste or type the actual code/message directly into the post. While images and screenshots can be helpful for providing context, the post should still be clear and useful without them. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)—the same reasoning applies to error messages as well.  Posts in which essential text is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you missed to add required dependencies for that module

For example
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions.x.x.x"